# Image load issues with www extention

Tags: image, cross-browser, load

I am having an image in safari with my images loading. If I leave off the 'www' extention the pages load just fine, however, if I include the 'www' it can't find certain images. The link to both are below ways are below. Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this? Safari is the only browser that is giving me issues with this. It works fine in Opera and IE 9.

[images load](http://bmckinnondesign.com/bwcollection.html)
[images won't load](http://www.bmckinnondesign.com/bwcollection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using canonical URLs?   Meaning using an `.htaccess` file to direct all your traffic to OR away from `www`?

I would include the following in the root .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will force EVERYTHING to `www.yoursite.com` ...  So images and web pages will require `www` in the address, and if they are called by `http://yoursite.com/image/image.gif`  --  It will change the request to `http://www.yoursite.com/images/image.gif` dynamically.

Comment: I put that in and it forwards everything to the 'www' address, but the images still don't load on the 'www' pages.